# How do you close card view in iOS 13 by sliding it down

Tags: swift, xcode, segue, swift5

Every time I perform a segue from the new iOS 13 card view, it messes up my UI changes occasionally for whatever reason. Instead of the user manually sliding it down to leave the view, how do I do this "swipe down" segue programmatically?

Comment: Does calling `self.dismiss()` not do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: OMG YOU ARE AMAZING!!!!!!!! Thank you. This is exactly what I couldn't figure out.